# Material colors are showing only after render in Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm new to blender and started to create something using tutorials. I created an object and added some colors to it then render the object and everything worked fine then I saved it.

But when I opened the saved blender file again it is not showing any of colors but when I render it shows the same object as I saves with colors.

Not sure if something changed in the settings.

[image]

The rendered Image:

[image]

Comment: when you reopen the file, the 3D view will switch back to Solid mode instead of Render mode (small sphere icons on the top right of your 3D view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default blender viewport solid mode does not show material colors, you can see 4 viewport shading modes in the upper right corner

[image]

Those are in order, left to right: wireframe, solid, material preview and rendered. By default material

By default solid shading will not show materials, but material preview and rendered will.